# Different randomized background image for multiple divs

Tags: javascript

How would I go about alternating the background with random images of each div with similar properties using javascript? (Not all the divs should be the same image, though there may be overlaps if the image pool is small)

I have multiple divs with the same properties, in my case:

```
<div class="background" id="bgimg"></div>
```

I also have a folder (images/) that has obj1.jpg, obj2.jpg ... obj5.jpg

So far I have a javascript code:

```
function bckg(){
            var images = ['obj1.jpg', 'obj2.jpg', 'obj3.jpg', 'obj4.jpg', 'obj5.jpg'];
            var div = document.querySelector('#bgimg');
            div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')';
            }
```

However, not all divs end up with randomized images. Rather only the first div shows a randomized image.

How would I go about making each div have a randomized image?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Same properties? You mean they have the same ID's? That may be why it only works for the first..

Comment: "I have multiple divs with the same properties" Does that mean all your divs have the same ID?

Comment: Search on the class not id

Comment: Randomize the order of your images array then assign divs in the order of the images array.

Comment: Each of my divs looks like `<div class="background" id="bgimg"></div>`
I should've caught that I should search on class. However, despite changing it to search for .background, no images popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only selects the first item. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Try `document.querySelectorAll` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and then loop through each of the items returned.

Also, as other people have mentioned, an ID is supposed to be unique. If you want to have multiple divs with the same property, you should use matching classes.

Comment: I think you solved my problem! I don't have much background in javascript so thanks for pointing out my mistakes and explanations.